# SQL - Joining rows from the same date together, and working out the time difference between them both

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2012

First post to apologies if the format is incorrect.

I'm trying to find the time difference between 2 rows with the same date,and then group them by that date. Current structure of the table is below.

```
Day    Date    Time         Property_Name

MON  2019-07-01  20:52:15   PropertyName1
MON  2019-07-01  22:45:56   PropertyName1
WED  2019-07-03  20:54:59   PropertyName1
WED  2019-07-03  22:42:46   PropertyName1
FRI  2019-07-05  20:55:06   PropertyName1
FRI  2019-07-05  22:47:37   PropertyName1
```

```
Select 
[Day],
,cast[Date] as date) as [Date]
,cast[Time] as date) as [Time]
,Property_Name
From table
```

Ideally, i'd like something that shows like below.

```
Day  Date         Time1      Time 2   Time Difference    Property_Name
MON  2019-07-01  20:52:15   22:45:56    01:53:41         PropertyName1
WED  2019-07-03  20:54:59   22:42:46    01:47:47         PropertyName1
FRI  2019-07-05  20:55:06   22:47:37    01:52:31         PropertyName1
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you using mysql, or sql-server ? Please just put one database tag, date funtions are notably vendor specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation.  The simplest method is to get the difference in seconds:

```
select day, date, min(time) as time1, max(time) as time2,
       datediff(second, min(time), max(time)) as duration_seconds,
       propertyname
from t
group by day, date, propertyname;
```

If it is important to return the difference as a time, you can use:

```
convert(time,
        dateadd(seconds,
                datediff(second, min(time), max(time)),
                0)
       )
```

Or format the value as a string.

Answer (score 0):

This works with a table called mytable:

```
SELECT
t1.Day AS Day,
t1.Date AS Date,
t1.Time AS Time_1, 
t2.time AS Time_2, 
timediff(t1.Time,t2.Time) AS difference,
t1.Properoperty AS Porperty 
FROM mytable t1 
JOIN mytable t2 
ON t1.Date = t2.Date 
WHERE t1.Time <> t2.Time 
GROUP BY t1.Day
```